# How to iterate through a list of items then write to DynamoDB efficiently?

Tags: node.js, csv, amazon-dynamodb

I'm a beginner and trying to work through this problem. I have a list of 3000 items in CSV that I need to process each day and update to DynamoDB table. I iterate through the list in NodeJS. In each loop, I fire a conditional update to DynamoDB to update each entry.

However, wouldn't this approach not work with DynamoDB as now I have a burst of 3000 write request in a second and have nothing in the rest of 24 hours.

Here are some of my thoughts:

1. Sequential write: Waiting the previous write to complete before continuing to the next one? I think this will overload my write capacity as well
2. Using some sort of Messaging queue service? This seems overkill as the program I'm writing is a simple service to parse a CSV file daily.

What kind of approach do I need to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of scenario sounds like DynamoDB [on-demand capacity mode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.OnDemand) would serve you well. That way you are paying for just the operations you do and storage. When you are not doing any operations, you just pay for storage.

Comment: Thank you. If I used mysql instead, would doing a 3000 writes during the iteration be a bad practice?

Comment: @user2727691 I do not know mysql well enough to answer your question, sorry.